# how to transfer dataset from t2 to tarchive on a condtion and delete then from t2

Tags: sql

[image]

I have 3 tables t1,t2 and tarchive, I want to transfer only records from t2 into tarchive that are not included in t1 and then delete from t2.

below is the solution I have but it doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO tarchiv
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(t1.id) FROM t1 as a, t2 as b WHERE a.t1id = b.t2id) = 0;

DELETE FROM t2
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(idangeb0t) FROM t1 as a, t2 as b WHERE a.t1id = b.t2id) = 0;
```

can someone help me out with it?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the syntax INSERT INTO ... SELECT using a left join onto t1 and a condition where t1.id is null. This means that we do not insert any values which are in t1.
NB This is in mySQL. Depending on your RDBMS there may be modifications of the syntax INSERT INTO ... SELECT

UPDATE FOLLOWING COMMENT
If we only want to delete the values not in t1 from t2 we can use

```
delete from t2 where id not in (select id from t1);
```

> ```
> create table t1 (id int);
> create table t2 (id int);
> create table tarchive (id int);
> insert into t1 values(1),(2),(3);
> insert into t2 values(3),(4);
> ```

> ```
> select * from t1;
> select * from t2;
> select * from tarchive;
> ```

> ```
> insert into tarchive(id)
> select t2.id 
> from t2 
> left join t1 on t2.id = t1.id
> where t1.id is null;
> delete from t2;
> ```

> ```
> select * from t1;
> select * from t2;
> select * from tarchive;
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
>
> | id |
> | -: |
>
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e029d4debfb8df05b4fbadadd57fb453)*

Comment: i tried it but it deletes all the ids in t2, i just wanted the id 4 in t2 to be deleted which wasn't included in t1.

Comment: OK - you just wrote "and then delete from t2." so I thought you meant everything. In that case you can use `delete from t2 where id not in (select id from t1);`

Comment: got ya, thanx....!

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO tarchive(id)
SELECT b.id
FROM t2 AS b
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT *FROM t1 AS a

```
WHERE a.id =b.id
```

)
delete from t2 AS b
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT *FROM t1 AS a

```
WHERE a.id =b.id
```

)

we have found a solution :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).